# Does adding a +1/+1 counter count as "gaining attack?"

Tags: vs-2pcg

The Mystique Main Character has the following Level Up Power:

> ***Bitter Fury***
>
> **Level Up (10)** - Whenever Mystique gains ATK, she gains that much XP.

The [rules](http://www.upperdeck.com/OP/RuleBooks/Vs_System_2PCG_Rules-The_Marvel_Battles.pdf) have this to say about +1/+1 counters:

> Many effects put +1/+1 of -1/-1 counters on characters. These numbers alter a character's ATK and DEF until something removes the counters.

Does adding a +1/+1 counter to Mystique cause her to "gain attack," which  triggers her Level Up Power?

Answer (score 2):

From the FAQ at [VsSystem2PCG.AlterVista.org](http://vssystem2pcg.altervista.org/faq/faq-eng/?doing_wp_cron=1466083564.2965559959411621093750), regarding Mystique's Bitter Fury:

**Question**

> Does adding counters count as her gaining ATK? What about Trickster God switching her ATK/DEF, would she gain 5 xp as she turns into a 6/1?

**Answer**

> Yes and Yes.

Comment: This is a handy resource. I'm curious who is providing answers to the questions on this website. The website links to the FAQ from UpperDeck, but that hasn't been updated since September of 2015. Where are the answers for the Defenders and A-Force expansions coming from? It's probably written on the site somewhere, but I don't read Italian and not everything is translated.